Calculating death rates for an increasing population over the long-term
I'm part of a small long-term outcomes study for a specific MH intervention. We're becoming a little alarmed at the number of subjects who seem to have died in their 20s and we'd like to make sure that the death rate is, in fact, unusually high and start making some noises about the potential problem.

Briefly, we have a population of about 600 subjects who were admitted to a MH facility over a period of 25 years. They were admitted to this facility as teenagers over the years and their current ages range 20-50.
What we'd like to do is calculate the death rates in 5 year intervals (15-19, 20-24, etc.) so we can compare it to gen pop and more specific/relevant populations.

At face value, this feels like a basic problem, but I simply do not know how to engage with the fact that we have to look at a 25 year horizon with a population that kept growing over that time period (and is now stable). If someone could hold my hand and point me in the right conceptual direction I would appreciate it! Thanks

Welcome to CrossValidated.  Can you pinpoint each individual's start time and (if applicable) time of death?  Also, is the intervention ongoing for each person over the course of up to 25 years?

@rolando2 Thank you. Yes, we've got that info for each individual. The intervention has concluded for all individuals (and it was also of varying duration following admission at varying ages).
Our understanding is also that there is no obvious link between the duration of the intervention and outcomes. The point we'd like to be able to make is probably outside the intervention itself--that the population is dying at disproportionate rates in their 20s.

Survival analysis (a.k.a. time-to-event or duration modeling) is a very flexible and comprehensive way to address this problem.  It would likely require a statistician.
